# Reading and writing to a file for authentication

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make a simple authentication system in c#. I am trying to make it read a text file and if it has the correct answer/username, continue. If it doesn't it has a textbox.Show on it. My current code for this is:

```
if(textBox1.Text == "wlkey1")
{
    Hide();
    string fileName1 ="authentication.txt";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName1, textBox1.Text);
}
else{
    MessageBox.Show("Yikes. That's incorrect.", "Uh oh.");
}
```

Comment: does `authentication.txt` contain the password, or does it contain information only an "authenticated" person should be able to see?  `textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName1);` might be what you need

Comment: Please be more clear about what the question is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Writing to file instead of reading it. you must use `ReadAllText()`

```
string fileName1 ="authentication.txt";
string curPass = "someDefaultPass";
if(System.IO.File.Exists(fileName1)
    curPass = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName1);
if(textBox1.Text == curPass)
{
    Hide();
}
else{
    MessageBox.Show("Yikes. That's incorrect.", "Uh oh.");
}
```

By the way, as you may already know, saving passwords on a file is not secure.

for writing well you have already done it:

```
string fileName1 ="authentication.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName1, textBox1.Text);
```